# How to install babel and using ES6 locally on Browser?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

So, I am  following tutorial to learn ES2015 on here:

http://k33g.github.io/2015/05/02/ES6.html

But, I don't find this file based on that tutorial:

```
node_modules/babel-core/browser.js
```

Where can I get browser.js? Because after I execute:

```
npm install babel-core
```

there are 2 browser.js in `node_modules\babel-core`

```
1 node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\register\browser.js
2 node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\browser.js
```

Which one should I copy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `babel` 6.2.0 `browser.js` has been removed.

Following [Babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/), you have two options:

**1. Use `babel-standalone`:**

It is a standalone build of Babel for use in non-Node.js environments, including browsers. It is a replacement of `babel-browser` and is used in the official Babel [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl)

**2. Bundle your own file:**

Use a bundler like browserify/webpack and require directly `babel-core` npm module and make sure to configure correctly browserify or webpack to avoid error due to pure node dependencies and so on.

Example of config using webpack (I left only the one specific):

```
{
    ...
    module: {
      loaders: [
        ...
        {
          loader: 'json-loader',
          test: /\.json$/
        }
      ]
    },
    node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      module: 'empty',
      net: 'empty'
    }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
import {transform} from 'babel-core';
import es2015 from 'babel-preset-es2015';
import transformRuntime from 'babel-plugin-transform-runtime';

...
transform(
        /* your ES6 code */,
        {
          presets: [es2015],
          plugins: [transformRuntime]
        }
      )
...
```

Note that plugins and presets need to be required from the code and can't be passed as string option.

Comment: So... Webpack could mock node modules, that's cool. I thought I'd never make it build before Babel release a guide on using Babel 6 in browsers.

Answer (score 10):

In-browser transpiling has been removed from Babel 6, however Daniel15 has created a standalone build for use in "non-Node.js environments including browsers" here:

https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone

All you need to do is add this reference to your page:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>`

And then make sure you're using the `script type="text/babel"` attribute in your references to other script files.

UPDATE:
More info can now be found here: [babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html)

Comment: is this support export and import feature? Recently, i use import and export feature using gulp + babelify + browserify + vinyl-source-stream

Comment: The correct repo is now in `@babel` at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html

Comment: Further following @BrianM.Hunt comment: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-standalone

Answer (score 10):

An example of the async/await using babel standalone!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Standalone Async/Await Example</h1>
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017, stage-3" data-plugins="syntax-async-functions">
/* Output of Babel object */
console.log('Babel =', Babel);

var users = { '123' : { name : 'Joe Montana'} };
process();
async function process()
{
 var id = await getId(); 
 console.log("User ID: "+id);
 
 var name = await getUserName(id); 
 console.log("User Name: "+name);
}
function getId()
{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('calling'); resolve("123"); }, 2000);
 });
}
function getUserName(id)
{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('requesting user name with id: '+id); resolve(users[id].name); }, 3000);
 });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `browser.js` from `babel-browser` package: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/

And best of all to use a compilation on the server side.

Comment: there is no `babel-browser` inside `node_modules/babel-core/` man

Comment: You need install that package: `npm install babel-browser --save`

Comment: babel-browser 6.1.19 does not seem compatible with babel 6.2.0

Comment: Related github discussion: https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/c0afdfd1a83aab0c25a1fc23cee0b09d560f4d35

Comment: Does anyone know of a good recipe for fitting react/JSX server side transpiling into a django workflow? It's all very well if using a node backend - but we're not.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,stage-2">
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.hnpwa.com/v0/news/1.json')
    console.log(res)
</script>
```